# Understanding how server process request on single cpu same machine or remote machine?apa

Tags: apache, server, process, multiprocessing

I am new to programming and learning client server model.We know that in single core machine on process runs at a time.in client server model when we create web server using apache,running nodejs and php application.How it process our request
If apache server is also a process it means it need cpu as per my understanding and so other process will be in queue .and if apache directs request to some other node js process or php process using threads it means either one of then need cpu to process request and apache will be queue.
**My real concern is how CPU is utilised and behaves** between all these process.How apache  ,node and php process shares CPU among themseleves
Same concern how localhost server and my web app ( both are process) using my single cpu?
What is missing node in my understanding of server process

Answer (score 0):

Operating systems use a real-time scheduler to apportion a small time slice of CPU time to each process in the system in turn. Typically, the time slice each process is executing is in the order of 10 milli-seconds.

Real time scheduling allows a CPU to operate multiple tasks (node, PHP, Apache etc) to run concurrently.

A ***simplified*** view of a when a new process time-slice begins (otherwise known as context switching) occurs-:

- the running process is suspended, it's state is preserved in memory
- the state of the next process is retrieved from memory and loaded into the CPU's registers.
- The new process is executed for it's time slice.

Not all processes have the same priority, so key processes may get more execution time slice than others.

The time slice may be terminated early, say when the running process requires I/O (say a key press from the keyboard, or when data is to be read from disk). This is known as a hardware interrupt. A hardware device (e.g. keyboard or hard disk) interrupts the process, and triggers the scheduler to start the next process. The process is suspended (it's waiting for the key-press or the data to be placed into memory, so the CPU can get on with another task). Execution of next process in the process queue is then resumed.

~

Comment: Thanks ,i understand this concept of context switching .Does it mean apache server also time slices which is against argument that server is continous running process?

Comment: Yes, apache has one or several processes managing web requests. Each one is executed by the scheduler with frequent time slices. There is no continuous running process. The OS scheduler gives the *impression* of continuous process execution.